# Network Fetch Errors on Specifically Mobile Chrome and Safari Browsers

Tags: javascript, fetch, systemjs

Our application is making a fetch request through SystemJS and we have been noticing many network fetch errors on specifically mobile browsers. We haven't been able to reproduce this error.

The 2 most common error messages are:

1. `TypeError: cancelled` -- *this occurs most frequently on Mobile Safari v14*
2. `TypeError: Failed to fetch` -- *this occurs most frequently on Chrome Mobile v91*

---

Just for reference, we have a script as follows:
`<script src="<import map link>" type="systemjs-importmap" onerror="retryFunction()"></script>`

This script is processed by SystemJS, [which calls fetch using the script.src](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/3282137c15b51eab60ea165ca644bde62792a945/src/features/import-maps.js#L49)

---

We have tried adding retry logic which invokes another fetch but it is not helping.
In the network tab of the web Chrome browser I don't see any CORS errors and get a 200 on the OPTIONS and GET requests. To that point, we see this error happening more on mobile over desktop.

Would anyone have any insight on this issue?

Comment: One reason for an async request to be _cancelled_ is if you navigate away from the current page. If you're triggering these requests from user events (like _click_) are you making sure you're preventing the default event action?